# Get trimmed text from Text Area control using Perl Win32::GUI

Tags: perl

How to retrieve the trimmed text (LTRIM and RTRIM) from a TextArea control.
The TextArea control has been created through Win32::GUI module.

```
use strict;
use Win32;
use Win32::GUI;


my $DOS = Win32::GUI::GetPerlWindow();
Win32::GUI::Hide($DOS);

my $main_window=Win32::GUI::Window->new(
        -name => 'main_window',
        -text => 'main_window_Test',
        -left => 375,
        -top  => 200,
        -width =>510,#370,
        -height =>220,
        -background => [190,190,190],
        -dialogui   => 1,
        -maximizebox => 0,
  );

my $Entry_Path=$main_window->AddTextfield(
        -name => 'entrypath',
        -pos => [220,66],
        -size => [180,23],
        -align => 'left',
        -foreground => [],
        -tabstop => 1,
  );


my $get_trim_Button=$main_window->AddButton(                     
        -text => 'Create Trimmed texts',
        -name =>  'ncxcreate',
        -size => [110,20],
        -align=>center,
        -pos  =>  [255,150],
        -background =>  [190,190,190],
        -foreground => [],
        -tabstop => 1,
        -disabled=>1
  );

$main_window->Show();
Win32::GUI::Dialog();

sub ncxcreate_Click{
 my $text_received=$Entry_Path->Text;
}
```

In the above code I need to retrieve the trimmed text value(leading and trailing spaces removed texts) in the $text_received scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for a trim function?

```
sub trim { ( my $s = $_[0] ) =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; $s }

sub trim { $_[0] =~ s/^\s+|\s+$/gr }  # 5.14+
```

Use /m as well to remove leading and trailing spaces from each line.

```
sub trim_multi { ( my $s = $_[0] ) =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//mg; $s }

sub trim_multi { $_[0] =~ s/^\s+|\s+$/mgr }  # 5.14+
```

Comment: Thanks...and I would like to know one more thing..Is any inbuilt function available for the same?